# Dealing with unique measurement at specific time-steps

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to identify the number of unique measurement times. Based on the below example at t1 there is one unique measurement (e.g. 1). Two is not a unique measurement because it occurs twice at different positions. At t2 there is 0 unique measurement, at t3 there are again three unique measurements and at t4, t5, t6 and t7, there are zero. Therefore the sum of the total unique measurement is 4.

Data format:

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Sample data

```
df<-structure(list(t1 = c(1, 2, 2), t2 = c(1, 1, 1), t3 = c(1, 3, 
4), t4 = c(2, 2, 2), t5 = c(3, 3, 3), t6 = c(3, 3, 3), t7 = c(1, 
1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    t1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), t2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), t3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), t4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), t5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), t6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), t7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(
  list(
    t1 = c(1, 2, 2),
    t2 = c(1, 1, 1),
    t3 = c(1, 3, 4),
    t4 = c(2, 2, 2),
    t5 = c(3, 3, 3),
    t6 = c(3, 3, 3),
    t7 = c(1, 1, 1)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-3L),
  spec = structure(
    list(
      cols = list(
        t1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")),
        t7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))
      ),
    default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector")),
    delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),
  class = c("spec_tbl_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  arrange(name, value) |> 
  count(name, value) |> 
  filter(n == 1) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  summarise(meas_num = str_c(value, collapse = ", "), count = sum(n))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name  meas_num count
#>   <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1 t1    1            1
#> 2 t3    1, 3, 4      3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>